# Angular ng-options gives empty select option on splice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have an Angular view that has the following markup:

```
<select id="ddlHandheldIds"
        name="ddlHandheldIds"
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="vm.handheldPayment.handHeldId"
        ng-options="id as id for id in vm.handheldKeys track by id"
        required
        title="select hand held id">
        <option value="">select hand held id</option>
</select>
```

The `vm.handheldKeys` when page is loaded is an array with two values `[0,24]`.

When the page loads, the rendered HTML is the following (tabbed for readability):

```
<select id="ddlHandheldIds" name="ddlHandheldIds" 
        class="form-control ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required" 
        ng-model="vm.handheldPayment.handHeldId" 
        ng-options="id as id for id in vm.handheldKeys track by id"    
        required="" 
        title="select hand held id">
    <option value="" class="">select hand held id</option>
    <option value="0" label="0">0</option>
    <option value="24" label="24">24</option>
</select>
```

This, of course, is what you'd expect.

Now, through some business logic, after the user has interacted with the page, there's a function that *splices* the `vm.handheldKeys` array.  So, let's say the code looks like the following:

```
vm.handheldKeys.splice(0,1);  // Remove the '0' from the array
```

Now, what I get is the following rendered HTML (notice the first select option):

```
<select id="ddlHandheldIds" name="ddlHandheldIds" 
        class="form-control ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required" 
        ng-model="vm.handheldPayment.handHeldId" 
        ng-options="id as id for id in vm.handheldKeys track by id"    
        required="" 
        title="select hand held id">
    <option value="? string:0 ?"></option>
    <option value="" class="">select hand held id</option>
    <option value="24" label="24">24</option>
</select>
```

What's the best way to remove the item from the array without creating that additional option?  Is this a bug?

I debug my JavaScript in WebStorm and, sure enough, there's only one item in the array after the splice.

Thanks.

### UPDATE:

I also tried adding a filter and setting my options source to the filter, but I still get the same result.

```
    vm.filteredHandheldKeys = function() {
        var ids = handheldPayments.map(function(pmt) { return pmt.handHeldId; });

        if (!vm.handheldKeys) return;

        return vm.handheldKeys.filter(function(key) {
            return ids.indexOf(key) == -1;
        });
    };
```

### UPDATE 2:

Just FYI, if I was to perform

```
vm.handheldKeys.splice(1,1);  // Remove the '24' from the array
```

The select option now reads:

```
<option value="? string:24 ?"></option>
```

It may have to do with this form in which the the select box is located is in a modal? Perhaps the modal isn't getting re-rendered correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOOO, my final update was correct, because it was being rendered in the modal, the option was being removed from the angular model *after* the modal was being rendered (in the middle of a digest).  so, angular wasn't picking up the change.  What I ended up doing was changing the logic to remove the item while the modal was closed.

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is perfectly fine so you check once again that you just write your code as below :

```
<select id="ddlHandheldIds" name="ddlHandheldIds"
        class="form-control ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required"
        ng-model="vm.handheldPayment.handHeldId"
        ng-options="id as id for id in vm.handheldKeys track by id"
        required=""
        title="select hand held id">
        <option value="" class="">select hand held id</option>
      </select>
```

and for slice you use your code as like  : -

```
 <input type="button" name="name" value="Splice" ng-click="vm.splice()">
```

in the vm.splice function your code looks like-

```
vm.handheldKeys = [0,24];
  vm.splice = function () {
        vm.handheldKeys.splice(0,1);
      }
```

I check it on my machine and this is perfectly fine.

"HAPPY CODING"

Comment: yeah, i'm not sure what's causing this. if it matters, the app is running angular 1.3.15

Comment: can you check in console of your browser if there is any error show. angular 1.3.15 has no issue with this code.

Comment: no errors.  i even tried just doing a filter (recheck my post).  But I still get the same result